# Use comma separated values in where clause and compare it with in clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is the edited question with full problem. Following is the table structure. (Only necessary columns are shown below.)

Table Name: `tblQualificationMaster`.

```
Qualiid  QualiName
-------  ---------
1        S.S.C  
2        H.S.C  
3        B.Sc  
4        M.C.A  
5        M.Sc(IT)  
6        B.E  
7        M.B.A  
8        B.Com  
9        M.E  
10       C.S  
12       M.Com
```

Table Name: `tblAppResumeMaster`.

```
AppId  FirstName  LastName  TotalExpYears  TotalExpMonths  
-----  ---------  --------  -------------  --------------
1      Rahul      Patel     7              0  
2      Ritesh     Shah      0              0  
3      Ajay       shah      7              6  
4      Ram        Prasad    7              6  
5      Mohan      Varma     5              0  
6      Gaurav     Kumar     8              0
```

Table Name: `tblAppQualificationDetail`. (For better reading I am writing comma separated value for all rows except first row but in my database all values are stored like for `appid=1`. i.e one row for each `qualificationid`.)

```
Appid  QualiId  
-----  -------
1      1  
1      2  
1      3  
1      4  
2      1,2,3  
3      1,2,6  
4      1,2,3,5  
5      1,2,3,4  
6      1,2,6,9
```

Table Name: `tblVacancyMaster`

```
VacId  Title           Criteria  Req.Exp  KeySkills
-----  --------------  --------  -------  ---------------
1      Programmer      4,5,6     4        .net,java,php
2      TL              4,5       3        .net,java,php
3      Project Mngr.   4,6,9     4        .net,java,php,sql
4      Java Developer  4,5,6     0        java,oracle,sql
5      Manager         7,9       7        bussiness management
6      Supervisior     3,8       3        marketing
7      PHP Developer   4,5       0        php,mysql,send
```

Now based on this detail I want to create view which should have following fields. (It is shown for `VacId=1` but I need this for all vacancies so that I can fire where clause on this view like `select * from view where VacId=3`.)

```
AppId  FirstName  LastName  QualiName  QualiId  TotalExp  VacId  VacTitle
-----  ---------  --------  ---------  -------  --------  -----  ----------
1      Rahul      Patel     M.C.A      4        7         1      Programmer
3      Ajay       Shah      B.E.       6        7         1      Programmer
5      Mohan      Verma     M.C.A      4        5         1      Programmer
6      Gaurav     Kumar     B.E        6        8         1      Programmer
6      Gaurav     Kumar     M.E        9        8         1      Programmer
```

This view shows AppId 1,3,5 and 6 are eligible for vacancy 3 but it shows duplicate entry for app 6. How can I get unique records?

I may be wrong in database design because this is my first project and I am learning database, so let me know and correct if something goes against database standards.

My previous query 
(Note: Earlier I was using one intermediate table `tblVacancyCriteriaDetail` which was having columns `VacId` and `QualiId` and my table `tblVacancyMaster` was not having column criteria)

```
select
  ARM.AppId,
  ARM.AppFirstName,
  ARM.AppLastName,
  ARM.AppMobileNo,
  AQD.QualiId,
  VacQualiDetail.QualiName,
  ARM.AppEmailId1,
  VacQualiDetail.VacID,
  ARM.TotalExpYear,
  VacQualiDetail.VacTitle,
  VacQualiDetail.DeptId,
  VacQualiDetail.CompId,
  CM.CompName  
from
  tblAppResumeMaster ARM,
  tblAppQualificationDetail AQD,
  tblCompanyMaster CM,
  (
    select
      VM.VacID,
      VM.VacTitle,
      VM.CompId,
      VM.DeptId,
      vcd.QualificationID,
      QM.QualiName,
      VM.RequiredExperience as Expe
    from
      tblVacancyCriteriaDetail VCD,
      tblVacancyMaster VM,
      tblQualificationMaster QM
    where VCD.VacID=VM.VacID
      and VCD.QualificationID=QM.QualificationId
      and VM.Status=0
  ) as VacQualiDetail
where AQD.AppId=arm.AppId
  and aqd.QualiId=VacQualiDetail.QualificationID
  and ARM.TotalExpYear>=Expe
  and cm.CompId=VacQualiDetail.CompId
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: I don't have a solution for SQL Server but you should re-think that design. You are violating a fundamental principle of relational database design and that's why this problem is so complicated to solve.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please tell me which rule has been violated???

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse: First normal form

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question. Please have a look it again. Earlier I show only part of my problem

Comment: to eliminate the duplicate appid you could use a group by appid

Comment: since QualiId dont have more specific columns, i would integrate it into tblAppResumeMaster

Comment: @Dementic. Group by will not work in this case as I am not using any aggregate function.

Comment: its really hard to not have any way to test my answers, please excuse me.
if GROUP BY would not work, you could try and use a DISTINCT,
but i dont really understand why you say it will not work.
since the view will have some kind of a join on it ( to show qName )

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse, tblVacancyMaster has a column Criteria. This column actually has comma separated values or it's just for better reading too like in tblAppQualificationDetail?

Comment: @Karlois. No in table tblVacancyMaster, criteria column actually have comma separated values. All the things are as shown in the question except for the columns for which I have provided note.

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse, Ok. 2 questions: (1) What is Criteria? Is this comma separated quality ids? (2) Can you show your SQL which you use to get the last view?

Comment: @Dementic. Group by is of no use because if I will use group by, then I have tow write all column name in the group by clause which is not feasible solution. More over Distinct will also not work because distinct will look for the unique combination of columns which will always be there. It is not possible to write unique on single column when query is returning multiple columns.

Comment: @Karolis Criteria is the qualifications that an applicant is supposed to have to be eligible for particular vacancy. Earlier I was using separate table as tblVacancyMaster which was not having Criteria column and another table tblVacancyCriteriaDetail which was having two columns i.e VacId and QualiId. That means for each QualiId, there was one row.(e.g.for vacId1-3 columns) but my team leader wahts to do like this.

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse, Can you describe the relations between the tables which participate in the view? I have to know which relations are 1:M and which are 1:1

Comment: @Karolis..Relationship between AppId(tblAppResumeMaster) and QualiId(tblQualificationMaster) is 1:M. Relationship between VacId(tblVacancyMaster) and QualificationId(tblQualificationMaster) is 1:M. Relation between AppId(tblAppresumMaster) and VacId (tblVacancyMaster) is 1:M

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse, I think you made some mistakes in your previous comment because I don't see some relations in the query at all. By the way you have mentioned nothing about tblVacancyCriteriaDetail and tblCompanyMaster

Comment: @Chiraq Fanse, by the way, according to the information currently I have It's difficult to name the real problems, but I in my opinion the problem is in subselect. According to what I understand you added two tables (tblVacancyCriteriaDetail and tblVacancyMaster) to the table tblQualificationMaster only for to get the status, but depending on the relations it is possible that this subselect returns too many rows. Firsly try to check this subselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create view vAppList as
select AppId, 
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       QualiName, 
       Qualiid, 
       TotalExpYears, 
       VacId, 
       Title
from (select ARM.AppId,
             ARM.FirstName,
             ARM.LastName,
             QM.QualiName,
             QM.Qualiid,
             ARM.TotalExpYears,
             VM.VacId,
             VM.Title,
             row_number() over(partition by ARM.AppId, VM.VacId order by QM.Qualiid) as rn
      from tblAppResumeMaster as ARM
        inner join tblAppQualificationDetail as AQD
          on ARM.AppId = AQD.Appid
        inner join tblQualificationMaster as QM
          on AQD.QualiId = QM.Qualiid  
        inner join tblVacancyMaster as VM
          on  ','+VM.Criteria+',' like '%,'+cast(QM.Qualiid as varchar(10))+',%'    
     ) as V
where V.rn = 1
```

The sub query will have duplicate when one applicant matches more then one qualification. In that case `QualiName` will have the value for the lowest `Qualiid`.

If you go back to use tblVacancyCriteriaDetail, which I think you should, the view would look like this.

```
create view vAppList as
select AppId, 
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       QualiName, 
       Qualiid, 
       TotalExpYears, 
       VacId, 
       Title
from (select ARM.AppId,
             ARM.FirstName,
             ARM.LastName,
             QM.QualiName,
             QM.Qualiid,
             ARM.TotalExpYears,
             VM.VacId,
             VM.Title,
             row_number() over(partition by ARM.AppId, VM.VacId order by QM.Qualiid) as rn
      from tblAppResumeMaster as ARM
        inner join tblAppQualificationDetail as AQD
          on ARM.AppId = AQD.Appid
        inner join tblQualificationMaster as QM
          on AQD.QualiId = QM.Qualiid
        inner join tblVacancyCriteriaDetail as VCD    
          on QM.Qualiid = VCD.QualiID
        inner join tblVacancyMaster as VM
          on  VCD.VacId = VM.VacId
     ) as V
where V.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with MS SQL Server, so I think the best way would be to use Regex (try to find something about it in SQL Server documentation).

But I think this should work:

```
select * from Table1 Where (',' + qualificationid + ',') like '%,6,%';
```

I assume that string concatenation is done using `+` sign.

Comment: I agree. Thats's the only way to work around the broken design.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look it again. Earlier I show only part of my problem

Answer (score 0):

revised:

create a new function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @slice varchar(8000)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @slice = @String     

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        if len(@String) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
```

then you could use my prev answer:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ColumnID IN split(SELECT ColumnWithValues FROM TableB)
```

Comment: @Dementic It will not work as comma separated qualification ids are string. That means "4,6,9" is one string and qualification ids in table 2 are also string. As "4,6,9" is not similar to "1","2","6" or "9", it will not return any record

Comment: i am not sure you are right.
since when you do a select ( for one column ) the result would be the same as it is stored in that column.
i can not test it since i am on vacation, but if you could test it,
i am almost sure that it should work ( or not :D )

Comment: i think you are right, but am not sure.
this works well on MySQL but might fail on MSSql

Comment: Wont' work in MySQL either (because the conversion of the character value '4,6,9' will never match the numerical value 4 (or 6, or 9)

Comment: well, thx for the vote down...
but this DOES work on MySQL in an app ive developed.

Comment: @Dementic I think you misunderstood something. If you were wright this would be very unexpected behavior from developer's perspective. Your query is very useful but for absolutely different thing.

Comment: a nice explanations like yours might have made me try and rethink about a solution. but a vote down made me quit this one ;)

Comment: @Dementic I have updated my question. Please have a look it again. Earlier I show only part of my problem –

Comment: @Dementic: I tried it and it doesn't work (and no, I didn't vote your question down even though I was thinking about it)

Comment: sorry guyz, but i dont recall i asked "Who voted me down."
i just said that a nice comment would have made me change my answer.
btw, check my edited answer.

Comment: Vote up, snippets like these are gold

Answer (score 0):

try using `COALESCE` function to get your rows in one column with comma separeted.this is a simple examle

```
 declare @QualIDs varchar(50)=''
 select  @QualIDs= COALESCE(@QualIDs+ ', ', '') + CAST(Qualiid AS varchar(50)))
 from tblQualificationMaster
```

this will return all `Qualiid` with comma separated you can use it in where clause or in sub query.

to read more about `COALESCE` go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Miroprocessor I have updated my question. Please have a look it again. Earlier I show only part of my problem –